# How to get composite column name components

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

How can I get A composite column components from ByteBuffer?

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811762/how-to-get-components-of-a-composite-column-name-in-cassandra)

But got no response. I am now attempting to get the column name from a byte buffer as

```
        Composite start = new Composite();
    start.addComponent(System.currentTimeMillis(), LS);
    List<HColumn<Composite, String>> columns = cs.setRange(start, null, true, 10).execute().get().getColumns();

    for (HColumn<Composite, String> column : columns) {
        ByteBuffer bf = column.getNameBytes();
        Serializer<Composite> ns = column.getNameSerializer();
        Composite composite = ns.fromByteBuffer(bf);
// I get an exception from above line
        String value = column.getValue();
    }
```

My problem is that I have a column family with composite comparatator made of two LongType
Then I do a column slice on one of it's rows and from the columns List I want to get the Column name and get the individual components from it. Please someone help me I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
for (HColumn<Composite, String> column : columns) {
        for(Component<?> compositeComponent: column.getName().getComponents()) {
                Serializer<?> srz = compositeComponent.getSerializer();
                Object value = compositeComponent.getValue(srz);
        }
}
```

Comment: On the good side I thank you for your response sir, it's good to know that someone actually read and attempted to help me out. On the flip side, Your solution doesn't help since program breaks when column.getName() is invoked. Now posting the solution I have found. Apparently I can't answer my own question before 8 hours are over since asked. I noticed this problem when I run my project In Java EE 7 ie Glassfish 4.0 which comes with netbeans 7.3.1 But when I changed back to Java EE 6 the same code works. Can you please inverstigate this and file a bug report if it is.

Comment: Normally `column.getName()` should return an AbstractComposite instance. If it is broken you should put a debugger and check inside Hector to see what is going on